undefined reference to `__res_maybe_init@GLIBC_PRIVATE' got while installing krb5
During installing krb5 via brew install krb5, got this error:
gcc-14 -L../../lib -Wl,--enable-new-dtags -Wl,-rpath -Wl,~/opt/brew/Cellar/krb5/1.21.3/lib -g -O2   -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -I../../include -I../../include  -DKRB5_DEPRECATED=1 -DKRB5_PRIVATE  -g -O2 -Wall -Wcast-align -Wshadow -Wmissing-prototypes -Wno-format-zero-length -Woverflow -Wstrict-overflow
-Wmissing-format-attribute -Wmissing-prototypes -Wreturn-type -Wmissing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wunused-function -Wunused-label -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wunknown-pragmas -Wsign-compare -Werror=uninitialized -Wno-maybe-uninitialized -Werror=pointer-arith -Werror=int-conversion -Werror=incompatible-poin
ter-types -Werror=discarded-qualifiers -Werror=implicit-int -Werror=declaration-after-statement -Werror-implicit-function-declaration -pthread  -o test_getpw test_getpw.o -lkrb5support
~/opt/brew/opt/binutils/bin/ld: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2: undefined reference to `__res_maybe_init@GLIBC_PRIVATE'


when I check the /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2, there is indeed such a symbol __res_maybe_init@GLIBC_PRIVATE:
nm -D --with-symbol-versions /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2 | grep __res_maybe_init
                 U __res_maybe_init@GLIBC_PRIVATE

Further more, I tried to list shared library dependencies of /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2
$ ldd --verbose libresolv.so.2
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffc5f106000)
        libc.so.6 (0x00007f03328cc000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f0332e82000)

        Version information:
        ./libresolv.so.2:
                libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.14) => libc.so.6
                libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.4) => libc.so.6
                libc.so.6 (GLIBC_PRIVATE) => libc.so.6
                libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.2.5) => libc.so.6
                libc.so.6 (GLIBC_2.3) => libc.so.6
        libc.so.6:
                ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (GLIBC_2.3) => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
                ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (GLIBC_PRIVATE) => /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2


$ env | grep LD_LIBRARY_PATH
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=~/opt/brew/opt/binutils/lib:~/opt/brew/lib:~/opt/brew/opt/glibc/lib:

$ find ~/opt/brew/opt/glibc/lib -name "*libc.so*"
~/opt/brew/opt/glibc/lib/libc.so
~/opt/brew/opt/glibc/lib/libc.so.6


I think libresolv.so is supposed to depend on my own glibc under ~/opt/brew/opt/glibc/lib/libc.so.6, but I don't know how to fix it
$ ls ~/opt/brew/opt/glibc/lib | grep -e resolv
libresolv.a
libresolv.so
libresolv.so.2

$ ls /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu | grep -e resolv
libresolv-2.24.so
libresolv.so.2



Any ideas else i can try?

Problem solved after brew link glibc


Any ideas else i can try?

You are mixing different and mis-matching builds of GLIBC (libc.so.6 and libresolv.so.2 are both parts of GLIBC, and must come from the same build).
Further, you build is very unlikely to work, for reasons explained here.
If you are unwilling to use the system GLIBC, you must

Get a complete set of GLIBC libraries under ~/opt/brew/opt/glibc/lib (including libresolv.so.2 and all the other parts), and
Set the dynamic loader to ~/opt/brew/opt/glibc/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (as explained in the linked answer).

Update:

The dynamic version is already the one under ~/opt/brew/opt/glibc

Unfortunately we have no idea what hides behind your gcc-14 command. We know it invokes ~/opt/brew/opt/binutils/bin/ld, but not what arguments are passed to it.
One thing I noticed is that -lresolv is not on your command line. What I suspect is happening, is that ld observes that some other library on your link line requires libresolv.so.2, and guesses (incorrectly) which libresolv.so.2 it should use.
Adding -lresolv to the end of the link command line may fix this.
If it doesn't, you'll need to use gcc-14 -v ... to find out the actual link command it constructs.
P.S. Using ldd when you have multiple GLIBCs at different paths will end in tears: ldd will lie to you if you invoke the "wrong" one.

The dynamic version is already the one under ~/opt/brew/opt/glibc.
As to the mis-matching, I do believe there are both matched versions of system GLIBC and my own GLIBC (under ~/opt/brew/opt/glibc)
But why do dynamic linker ~/opt/brew/opt/binutils/bin/ld try to link another mis-matching one ?

@HolaYang I've updated the answer.
